# How do I identify which website on my server is under heavy traffic?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, top

I currently host one website on a server which many other websites use connect to via an API.

When I use the terminal command 'top' I can see www-data is the main culprit for my server running slow.

How do I identify which website is making the most API requests?  Is there a way to see the referrer for www-data?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are not logging requests, you can enable logs for a short period of time.  Then analyze the logs.  You can either parse them manually or use a log analyzer to find out who is making the most requests.

Using tools like sed/awk/grep, you can easily extract and print quick reports about referrer URLs, accessing IPs and other items.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716336/apache-log-analysis-unique-visitors-by-date-by-os

for tips on how to parse log files to get data.

Answer (score 2):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html

> The Status module allows a server administrator to find out how well their server is performing. A HTML page is presented that gives the current server statistics in an easily readable form. If required this page can be made to automatically refresh (given a compatible browser). Another page gives a simple machine-readable list of the current server state.